# How to fix aperture indicator in Minolta X700 viewfinder?

Tags: repair, viewfinder, minolta, mirror

I can't see the currently selected aperture when looking through the viewfinder of my Minolta X700. I've taken off the top front plate and found a little mirror loose inside, but have no idea where it's supposed to be glued to fix the problem. Have tried sticky taping it in number of locations and angles but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correctly, a small window above the aperture ring is used to project the selection to the viewfinder.